# Poedit and arrays in PHP/WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, translation, poedit

I have the following array in php

```
$arr = array ('five minutes', 'ten minutes', '15 minutes');
```

Also, at one point in my code, I am doing the following:

```
_e($arr[1]); // This is a WordPress function to display the translated output.
```

Now, how do I make sure that Poedit picks up the array entries for translation and eventually echo the translated output.

Comment: Do yo want to make sure that your text e.g. `$arr[1]` is translated or not?

Comment: Yes, I want `$arr[1]` to be translated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the array like this:

```
$arr = array (
    __( 'five minutes', 'your-text-domain' ),
    __( 'ten minutes', 'your-text-domain' ),
    __( '15 minutes', 'your-text-domain' )
);
```

Then simply `echo $arr[1];`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no translation, or the domain isn't loaded the original text is returned. So you can check this way:

```
if(__($text) != $text){
    // text can be translated
}
else{
    // text cannot translate
}
```